# How do I make a textview auto aline to textview?

Tags: xcode, image, textview

How can I have a textview auto-align to an image?

What I mean is, when I change an image from a square to a triangle, how do I make the textview fit inside that triangle automatically?

Check out my "Quick Notes!!" app on the app store for reference. I am using Xcode 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're going to have to do a bit of work to do what you want. I'm guessing you have a background image that changes from a square to a triangle and you want the textbox to remain inside of the shape. Since the imageview hosting the picture is still a rectangular shape the imageview dimensions don't actually change so you'd have to calculate or know the size of your triangle and scale the text box programatically based on a flag of whether or not you are displaying the triangle.

EDIT: Actually this is much simpler than i thought initially. Just position the textbox where you want it with what size in the .xib file and record the position and size. Then you simply check when you are displaying your triangle image and change the position and size of your textbox to what you had previously recorded.

Comment: Okay thanks so much. is there any way you could give me the code for that. Thanks

Comment: okay here is what i did.                                    textview.frame = CGRectMake(textview.frame.size.height, 110, textview.frame.size.width, 120);                                          But how from here do i make it move form right to left. The width just makes the text view bigger to the right. I need to MOVE it to the left. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure youre using CGRectMake correctly, I dont know your dimensions on the screen but it should be textview.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height); I think the way you have it at the moment incorrectly uses width and height twice.

Comment: Okay I did that but sense i am new to Xcode where would i place the numbers i want it to go to. Like when i did this i got an error        textview.frame = CGRectMake(xPos 70, yPos 70, width 70, height 70);

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I may have been a bit unclear, I was just listing out the arguments for the function that you need to call. You shouldn't include the words, xPos, yPos, etc, but instead include calls to the variables that contain those values.